# How to modify text color when app is minimized

Tags: android

How to modify text color when app is minimized ?

The color of action bar is white in toolbar, but when is minimized the text color turn black.

[PrintScreen Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEVOP.png)

Comment: You can't modify that. That is system defining the color based on the background color. The background color is based on the `accentColor` in your `color.xml` file. To test it, make the `accentColor` something dark (`#002b70`) and OS will make the text color white

Comment: Technically, you _could_ attempt to do it, by intercepting onPause (or onStop) and before calling super… changing the theme… using reflection, I mean, there may be ways, but I have never seen a valid reason from a UX standpoint about this (and hence why Google is possibly not providing this). Users identify a lot of things by shapes, sounds, *colors*, etc. Juggling colors for no reason, can only add confusion.

Comment: That being said, this question is not a good question for StackOverflow. It doesn’t provide any code or hint about what has been tested or not. You’re simply asking people to provide it for you (and most people are either going to reply incorrect things, or will give you the same things you could have found out by using any search engine). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define these combinations in color.xml file in res directory. This will help android system recognizing the color for your app. If you want help with color choosing, try this:

**https://material.io/color/**

Does this help you?

Comment: If I choose a color white for colorPrimary, the color when the app is minimized change ?

Comment: No it does not.